# Is there a way to get last created sub folder and its contents without giving the sub folder name or id?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to GAS. I need to get the last created subfolder and its contents from google drive and then make a copy of it in some other subfolder. Is there any way to do it?

I'm trying to work with `getDateCreated` or `getLastUpdated` but as per my knowledge, it won't get me the actual last created folder as someone might do some editing in other subfolders due to which I won't be able to get the last created subfolder.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('146Q-0X_ljV2K_q');
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var fol = folders.next();
    var fold = fol.getLastUpdated(); // needs last created folder 
    var fl = fol.getFiles(); // doesn't work gives error 
    Logger.log(fl);
  }
}

// this is just a  practice code for getting the last created folder in a parent folder.
```

I need the last created subfolder and then copy its contents to another subfolder in another parent folder.

Comment: Hello @Agha, welcome to Stackoverflow! I am somewhat confused by your second paragraph - could you please explain that a bit more? What are you exactly trying to accomplish? Bear in mind that `getLastUpdated` will return the time in which the folder's **properties** were last updated (it does not take into consideration any of its children). Cheers

Comment: Hello, @carlesgg97 thanks.  I need to extract a subfolder and its contents which were last created in a parent folder. For Example, ```Parent``` is my parent folder and ```child1``` is a subfolder and so on and the last created subfolder is ```child8``` which i want to get and its contents without calling it by id.

Comment: Hey @Agha, I have developed a script that does what you asked for. Kindly let me know whether that works for you. Cheers

Comment: I need to copy the last created subfolder contents into another folder's subfolder. I ran your code and it removes the whole folder which i don't need. I need a copy of Last created sub folder contents into another last created subfolder.

Comment: ``` function CopyFiles() {
  var srcFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('19mfofCO-UJYq3');
  var srcFol=srcFldr.getLastUpdated().getName();
  var srcFiles=srcFol.getFiles();
  var desFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('1WKv2462OX_lvGIcjV2K_q');
  var desFol=desFldr.getLastUpdated().getName();
  var desFiles=desFol.getFiles();
   var dfnA=[];
  while(desFiles.hasNext()) {
    var df=desFiles.next();
    dfnA.push(df.getName());
  }
  while(srcFiles.hasNext()) {
    var sf=srcFiles.next();
    if(dfnA.indexOf(sf.getName())==-1) {
      sf.makeCopy(sf.getName(),desFldr);
    }
  }
} ```

Comment: this is the code i'm working on.

Comment: Try this: `function getLastUpdatedSubFolder() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1zUNj0hrJUxcjGq5gvaIifMVwpOMVyIs2');
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  var fA=[];
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var fol = folders.next();
    fA.push({value:fol.getLastUpdated().valueOf(),folderId:fol.getId()});
  }
  fA.sort(function(a,b){return b.value-a.value;});
  var f=DriveApp.getFolderById(fA[0].folderId);
  //Logger.log(f.getName())
  return f;
}`

Comment: @Cooper it's not returning any value.

Comment: It’s returning a folder.

Comment: @Cooper yeah, it does the trick. I want to know another thing about csv sheets merging and deleting some specific data. Can you help?

Comment: Sure what’s the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```js
var ROOT_FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_ROOT_FOLDER_ID';
var DESTINATION_FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_DESTINATION_FOLDER_ID';

function moveFolder(folder, destinationFolder) {
  var folderParents = folder.getParents();
  while (folderParents.hasNext()) {
    folderParents.next().removeFolder(folder);
  }
  destinationFolder.addFolder(folder);
}

function getLastCreated(folder) {
  var dates = [folder.getDateCreated()];
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    dates.push(file.getDateCreated());
  }
  return Math.max.apply(Math, dates);
}

function myFunction() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1dFyAuwyVn3VFvMxZX2bzxf5K8ygdIol6');
  var folders = rootFolder.getFolders();
  var results = [];
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var folderId = folder.getId();
    var folderLastCreated = getLastCreated(folder);
    results.push({'folderId': folderId, 'folderLastCreated': folderLastCreated});
  }

  results.sort(mySort);

  var lastCreatedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(results[0].folderId);
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DESTINATION_FOLDER_ID);
  moveFolder(lastCreatedFolder, destinationFolder);
}

function mySort(a, b) {
  var a = a.folderLastCreated;
  var b = b.folderLastCreated;

  if (a > b) return -1;
  if (a < b) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

This will find the folder that has been last created (or that any of its children have been last created) and then move it to your destination folder. If  what you want is to move the folder that has been **least recently created**, you only have to modify the function `mySort(a, b)` for the following one:

```js
function mySort(a, b) {
  var a = a.folderLastCreated;
  var b = b.folderLastCreated;

  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

In order to make it work, please do remember to change the first two lines for your desired folder's ids.

Comment: let me try this and i'll let you know right after it gets compiled.

Comment: I've been trying to copy the contents of the ```parent1``` last created subfolder into ```parent2``` last created subfolder by comparing the already present content in it.

Comment: @AghaMusaKhan can you please add to your question a minimal but precise example of how would you like it to work? (describing the folder hierarchies and their files, and how would it look like before and after executing the script). That would help me understand your situation a lot! Cheers

Comment: In my google drive, there are two different folders ```parent1``` and ```parent2``` and they both have subfolders that automatically get created every week. What I want is to get the last created subfolder from ```parent1``` and it's content and copy its contents into ```parent2``` last created subfolder by comparing the file names and content, as some times both subfolder have same file name and contents. After that, I'll add a trigger that will automatically run the script every week and copy the contents of ```parent1``` subfolder into ```parent2``` subfolder.